# methods(http verbs) of all endpoints in current flask blueprint

Tags: rest, url, http-method, flask

I'm trying to generate the related links for each RESTful API endpoint **not just the current request**.   Another way which would also be acceptable, is that I want to generate all the endpoints of the current blueprint (in this case called 'blueprint_name'). Here is the abstract of my current setup:

```
def function_that_generates_links():
   #what should I put here?

blueprint_name = Blueprint('blueprint_name', __name__, url_prefix='/blueprint_name')

@blueprint_name.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def endpoint_name():
   #regular_data_being_sent_out is defined somewhere here
   return jsonify(data=regular_data_being_sent_out,
                  links=function_that_generates_links())

@blueprint_name.route('/other_place', methods=['POST'])
def endpoint_name_other():
   #regular_data_being_sent_out is defined somewhere here
   return jsonify(data=regular_data_being_sent_out,
                  links=function_that_generates_links())
@blueprint_name.route('/another_place', methods=['DELETE'])
def endpoint_name_another_place():
   #regular_data_being_sent_out is defined somewhere here
   return jsonify(data=regular_data_being_sent_out,
                  links=function_that_generates_links())

@blueprint_name.route('/yet_another_place', methods=['PUT'])
def endpoint_name_yet_another_place():
   #regular_data_being_sent_out is defined somewhere here
   return jsonify(data=regular_data_being_sent_out,
                  links=function_that_generates_links())
```

I want to append to each response emitted by each endpoint the appropriate http 'signatures' of all the other endpoints. In the example code above 'function_that_generates_links()' would be the function to do this.  I've already found that **url_encode() provides the necessary link I could use, but I also want the appropriate http verb** (GET,POST, DELETE...etc). It is finding the corresponding http-verb/method that I'm stuck on. The verb is important because without it the links are incomplete/useless.

Comment: What's wrong with using request.url and request.method?

Comment: I'll fix my response - but to be more specific. I want each endpoint to return the other endpoints. Using 'request' only gives the current request not all possible requests of the current blueprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list all current rules with `app.url_map.iter_rules()`. Then `rule.rule` should give you the URI expression and `rule.methods` a set with the available methods.

However, AFAIK, you can't do that for a blueprint, or filter by them. The blueprint stores the routes wrapped in lambda functions to be called when registered, and there's no easy way to unwrap that. If you need to go that way, it might be a better idea to subclass Blueprint, redefine the route method and preserve the parameters you want in the Blueprint instance itself.

Comment: this works perfectly, and after combing through what blueprints does it probably is the only way

Answer (score 1):

Marc,

request.method will return the method that was used to call the route you are in. For example if I had:

```
@bluprint_name.route('/someresource', methods=["GET", "POST", "DELETE"]):
def return_a_resource():
    return request.method
```

This would print the method that was used by the client.

To be clear, you cannot encode the method in the url itself. The client will have to read the method from a different field and call the url appropriately. The url is simply the location and the transport.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try to be more explicit in my question. While request does give the current request verb and url it doesn't give the other possible request urls/verbs.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to find the endpoints for a blueprint too. I came up with this snippet:

```
def rules_for_blueprint(bp):
if bp._got_registered_once:
    return [rule for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules() if rule.endpoint.split('.')[0]==bp.name]
else:
    raise Exception("Blueprint routes only exist after blueprint is registered")
```

It only works once the blueprint has been registered, but for my use case it is sufficient and I'm sure it will come in handy for others too.